# Retrieving an Oracle cursor from a Stored Procedure using Access 2003

Tags: oracle, ms-access, stored-procedures, vba, cursor

I need to retrieve data from an Oracle Stored Procedure.  The stored Procedure is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ATP_CONTRACT_SP
(
p_ContractNumber   IN   VARCHAR2,
p_ResultSet        OUT  ATPSP.cursorType
)
AS
BEGIN
OPEN p_ResultSet FOR
with t1 as (
select sc.c_ntp_no as ATP#, case when length(sc.c_proj_code) = 6 
...
from agt),
mt2 as (
select * from mt union select * from modagt
order by 3, 1 desc)
select mt2.atp#, mt2.llw#, '' as School, mt2.c_cont_type, mt2.approved, mt2.phase,          mt2.award, mt2.amendment,
mt2.totalaward, mt2.ATPApprvdOn,  mt2.rfp, mt2.balance, mt2.ctd_rfp
from mt2;
END;
```

The Access Code is as follows:

```
    Dim atpNumber As ADODB.Parameter, llwNumber As ADODB.Parameter, schoolString As ADODB.Parameter, _
    contractTypeString As ADODB.Parameter, approvedBool As ADODB.Parameter, _
    phaseString As ADODB.Parameter, awardNumber As ADODB.Parameter, _
    amendmentNumber As ADODB.Parameter, totalAwardNumber As ADODB.Parameter, _
    ATPApprovedOnDate As ADODB.Parameter, rfpNumber As ADODB.Parameter, _
    balanceNumber As ADODB.Parameter, ctd_rfpString As ADODB.Parameter

    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim connString As String
    connString = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};DSN=xxx;UID=xxx;PWD=xxx;SERVER=xxx"
    Dim rsCommand As ADODB.Command
    Set rsCommand = New ADODB.Command

   Set atpNumber = rsCommand.CreateParameter("atp#", adVarChar, adParamOutput, 20)
   Set llwNumber = rsCommand.CreateParameter("llw#", adVarChar, adParamOutput, 20)
   Set schoolString = rsCommand.CreateParameter("School", adVarChar, adParamOutput, 20, Null)
   Set contractTypeString = rsCommand.CreateParameter("c_cont_type", adVarChar, adParamOutput, 20)
   Set approvedBoolString = rsCommand.CreateParameter("approved", adVarChar, adParamOutput, 2)
   Set phaseString = rsCommand.CreateParameter("phase", adVarChar, adParamOutput, 35)
   Set awardNumber = rsCommand.CreateParameter("award", adNumeric, adParamOutput)
   Set amendmentNumber = rsCommand.CreateParameter("amendment", adNumeric, adParamOutput)
   Set totalAwardNumber = rsCommand.CreateParameter("totalaward", adNumeric, adParamOutput)
   Set ATPApprovedOnDate = rsCommand.CreateParameter("ATPApprvdOn", adDate, adParamOutput)
   Set rfpNumber = rsCommand.CreateParameter("rfp", adNumeric, adParamOutput)
   Set balanceNumber = rsCommand.CreateParameter("balance", adNumeric, adParamOutput)
   Set ctd_rfpString = rsCommand.CreateParameter("ctd_rfp", adVarChar, adParamOutput, 255)

   rsCommand.Parameters.Append atpNumber
   rsCommand.Parameters.Append llwNumber
   rsCommand.Parameters.Append schoolString
   rsCommand.Parameters.Append contractTypeString
   rsCommand.Parameters.Append approvedBoolString
   rsCommand.Parameters.Append phaseString
   rsCommand.Parameters.Append awardNumber
   rsCommand.Parameters.Append amendmentNumber
   rsCommand.Parameters.Append totalAwardNumber
   rsCommand.Parameters.Append ATPApprovedOnDate
   rsCommand.Parameters.Append rfpNumber
   rsCommand.Parameters.Append balanceNumber
   rsCommand.Parameters.Append ctd_rfpString

   Set rsRecords = rsCommand.Execute
```

On the `rsCommand.Execute` line there is an error message: Multiple-step OLEDB operation generated errors.  I've been working on this for two days and need to get this done.  And I'm interested in the technical challenge.

Where could I be going wrong?

Please alert me to any questions.

Answer (score 0):

## 1 you never set the rsCommand properties to specify the Oracle Procedure

## 2 it returns a recordset, not a series of parameters

You need 1 Input Parameter p_contractnumber advarchar
You need 1 Output Parameter P_resultset